# Unit testing private methods in Akka

Tags: java, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

I'm new to akka and I'm trying akka on java. I'd like to understand unit testing of business logic within actors. I read [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html) and the only example of isolated business logic within actor is:

```
static class MyActor extends UntypedActor {
  public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
    if (o.equals("say42")) {
      getSender().tell(42, getSelf());
    } else if (o instanceof Exception) {
      throw (Exception) o;
    }
  }
  public boolean testMe() { return true; }
}

@Test
public void demonstrateTestActorRef() {
  final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class);
  final TestActorRef<MyActor> ref = TestActorRef.create(system, props, "testA");
  final MyActor actor = ref.underlyingActor();
  assertTrue(actor.testMe());
}
```

While this is simple, it implies that the method I want to test is public. However, considering actors should communicate only via messages, my understanding that there is no reason to have public methods, so I'd made my method private. Like in example below:

```
public class LogRowParser extends AbstractActor {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogRowParser.class);

    public LogRowParser() {
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.
                        match(LogRow.class, lr -> {                                
                            ParsedLog log = parse(lr.rowText);
                            final ActorRef logWriter = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(LogWriter.class));
                            logWriter.tell(log, self());
                        }).
                        matchAny(o -> logger.info("Unknown message")).build()
        );
    }

    private ParsedLog parse(String rowText) {
        // Log parsing logic
    }
}
```

So to test method `parse` I either:

1. need it to make package-private
2. Or test actor's public interface, i.e. that next actor `LogWriter` received correct parsed message from my actor `LogRowParser`

My questions:

1. Are there any downsides on option #1? Assuming that actors communicating only via messages, encapsulation and clean open interfaces are less important?
2. In case if I try to use option #2, is there a way to catch messages sent from actor in test downstream (testing `LogRowParser` and catching in `LogWriter`)? I reviewed various examples on `JavaTestKit` but all of them are catching messages that are responses back to sender and none that would show how to intercept the message send to new actor.
3. Is there another option that I'm missing?

Thanks!

**UPD:**
Forgot to mention that I also considered options like:

- Moving logic out of actors completely into helper classes. Is it common practice with akka?
- Powermock... but i'm trying to avoid it if redesign is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no good reason to make that method private. One generally makes a method on a class private to prevent someone who has a direct reference to an instance of that class from calling that method. With an actor instance, no one will have a direct reference to an instance of that actor class. All you can get to communicate with an instance of that actor class is an `ActorRef` which is a light weight proxy that only allows you to communicate by sending messages to be handled by `onReceive` via the mailbox. An `ActorRef` does not expose any internal state or methods of that actor class. That's sort of one of the big selling points of an actor system. An actor instance completely encapsulates its internal state and methods, protecting them from the outside world and only allows those internal things to change in response to receiving messages. That's why it does not seem necessary to mark that method as private.

**Edit**

Unit testing of an actor, IMO, should always go through the `receive` functionality.  If you have some internal methods that are then called by the handling in `receive`, you should not focus on testing these methods in isolation but instead make sure that the paths that lead to their invocation are properly exercised via the messages that you pass during test scenarios.

In your particular example, `parse` is producing a `ParsedLog` message that is then sent on to a `logWriter` child actor.  For me, knowing that `parse` works as expected means asserting that the `logWriter` received the correct message.  In order to do this, I would allow the creation of the child `logWriter` to be overridden and then do just that in the test code and replace the actor creation with a `TestProbe`.  Then, you can use `expectMsg` on that probe to make sure that it received the expected `ParsedLog` message thus also testing the functionality in `parse`.

As far as your other comment around moving the real business for the actor out into a separate and more testable class and then calling that from in the actor, some people do this, so it's not unheard of.  I personally don't, but that's just me.  If that approach works for you, I don't see any major issues with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and this part specifically _An ActorRef does not expose any internal state or methods of that actor class. That's sort of one of the big selling points of an actor system_, it not only answers my question but helped me understand actor models better

Comment: You are right  (I voted your answer)  but you don't actually answered any of the concrete questions. Assuming you cannot change the given codebase, how would you act?

Comment: @JamesSharp, I added a little bit more detail.  I don't answer the questions  directly, but I do provide what I believe is a sound approach for testing actors.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't use "unit test" phrase for activity of testing through receive method, as it requires setting up ActorSystem which adds lot to what may be reason of test failing.

For me its rather integration test, which is slower and less isolated than unit test of single method.

Anyway I'm still looking for right balance between testing through receive method and having more logic outside of an actor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 3 years ago, when dealing with actors : the best approach i found was to have minimum responsability to the actor messenging responsability.
The actor will receive the message and choose the Object's method to call or the message to send or the exception to throw and that's it.
This way it will be very simple to mock up either the services called by the actor and the input to those services.